# Write a function which checks if a number is a square with recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

It is my first year in coding and for my homework, I have to find a recursive function that finds if the number given is square or not...

I have some ideas if I could use a non-recursive function. But I have no idea for recursive.

```
 bool estCarre(int a)
{
    bool t;
    t=true;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
    {
        if (i*i==a){
            return t=true;
        }
        if(i*i>a){
            return t=false;
        }
    }
    return t;   
}
```

Comment: How would you do it w/o recursion?  That might get you started toward a recursive solution.

Comment: Post your idea of non-recursive, perhaps then someone can give you a tip how recursify such function.

Comment: You might look at [general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion-or-from-a-recursion-to-a](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279004/general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion-or-from-a-recursion-to-a) to convert your current code to recursive one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a do-my-homework service.

Comment: @Jarod42@Quimby  bool int (a) {int t; t==1; while (t<a); { (t=t+1);} if (t*t==a); { true} else { false} return 0; } sorry i an typing on my phone i hope that i could explain it well enough

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am sorry if i made you feel like i am trying you guys to do my homework i wrote the non-recursive version on the function that i thought about in the latest comment

Comment: @T.K:  Please edit your post with your (compilable) code.  The code in the comments has some issues (such as ';' after `if` and `while`).

Comment: Please compile your code before you post it here. E.g. you can't name your function `int`. If it's the type of `a` you should add a name for the function. A compiler would message you these error.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I am sorry I just got home here is a compilable version: bool estCarre(int a)
{
 bool t;
 t=true;
  for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
 {
  if (i * i==a){
   return t=true;
  }
  if(i*i>a){
   return t=false;
  }
 }
 return t; 
}

Comment: Please don't comment code as it isn't readable. Edit your question and paste it there.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I just edited my post I think it is better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might transform:

```
bool estCarre(int a)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
    {
        if (i*i==a){
            return true;
        }
        if(i*i>a){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

into

```
bool estCarre(int a, int i = 1)
{
    // Loop content:
    if (i * i == a) {
        return true;
    }
    if (i * i > a) {
        return false;
    }
    // increment + loop condition + (recursive) loop
    if (i + 1 < a) {
        return estCarre(a, i + 1);
    }
    // outside loop
    return false;
}
```